# resize and adjust form controls as per the form resize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a sample windows application. In this application, I am making use of WinForms with FormBorderStyle set to sizable. Now, when I run my application, it shows the startup form which is re sizable. This form consist of various windows controls on it.
My problem is, when I resize the form, the controls on it do not get re size automatically.
Does anybody know how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set The Dock or Anchor properties of your controls accordingly.

Play with it, it's simple.

Comment: Thanks buddy,
I got it. I tried with Dock property, setting Dock acquires the whole area. I played with Anchor property of each control and it is working as I was looking for.